# Does object name has to start with lower case?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class Dish { 
}
```

File2

```
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
const DISHES: Dish[] = [
  {
    id: '0',
    name: 'Uthappizza',
    image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    featured: true,
    label: 'Hot',
    price: '4.99',
}
]
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  dishes: Dish[] = DISHES;
}
```

Why is it fetched using dish.name and dish.image and not Dish.name since the name is Dish[] and the class name is Dish

Html file

```
<img height="200px" src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
```

Comment: `dish` comes from a `*ngFor` in your template, iterating over `dishes`. That's an instance of your class (or a plain object matching the signature of your interface), but it isn't a static reference to your class. That is why it doesn't start with a capitalized letter.

Comment: You can but, no. With JavaScript Standards you are starting object names as you are doing, with upper case. But when you are declaring variable you need to start with lower case. ->  dishes: Dish[] - is right form.

Comment: @DatoGogshelidze those are naming practices and are not mandatory. You can create variables with capitalized letters, it just happens to be considered a bad practice by an opinionated documen, written by some guy who wanted a common way of writing variables.

Comment: @trichetriche I wanted to say what you sad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because Dish refers to a type, not a value here.

If you want to use the Dist class itself, you have to define it in the current component. And then you can only access to its static classes, like

```
export class Dish {
    static a: 10;
}

export class B {
    Dish = Dish; // Assign static variable Dish to the property Dish of the class B (same name)
}
```

then in the component which is implemented by class B, you can call this in the template

```
<div>{{ Dish.a }}</div>
<!-- will show 10 -->
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see here for example:
https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/styleguide/styleguide.md

Variables and functions in camelCase

Classes in PascalCase (capitalized camelCase)